# Installing Merlin - "In file included from daemon.h:11, from status.c:1: sql.h:4:21: error: dbi/dbi.h: No such file or directory" [RHEL]

Tags: redhat, nagios, make

Trying to install Merlin for Nagios, following the instructions in the [quick start guide](https://wiki.op5.org/merlin:docs:quickstart-centos5)
When I run the 'make' command I get the following errors:

```
sh gen-version.sh > version.c
    CC version.o
    LINK merlin.so
    CC status.o
In file included from daemon.h:11,
                 from status.c:1:
sql.h:4:21: error: dbi/dbi.h: No such file or directory
In file included from daemon.h:11,
                 from status.c:1:
sql.h:11: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_RESULT’
sql.h:25: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘sql_get_result’
status.c:28: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘result’
status.c: In function ‘prime_host_states’:
status.c:80: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘store_object_states’
status.c:80: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sql_get_result’
status.c:80: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
status.c: In function ‘prime_service_states’:
status.c:95: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
make: *** [status.o] Error 1
```

I couldn't find anything about how to fix this error. I'm on RHEL 5.5, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yum whatprovides '*/dbi/dbi.h'
```

Then pick the most appropriate package returned, and install it.